# VBA: Paste named range as value

Tags: vba, dynamic, copy, range, paste

I have a dynamic named range, call it "MYRange" in worksheet "Data1". By dynamic I mean that the range is coded as

```
=offset(A1,0,0, COUNTA(A:A),1).
```

The actual values that populate these cells are done via a vlookup. I want to copy this range into another workbook called "Data2" as values, otherwise I get a reference issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this programming, or formula manipulation in Excel?

Answer (score 2):

To copy values between two ranges use:

```
Range("MyDestRange").Value = Range("MySrcRange").Value
```

Make sure the two ranges are the same shape and number of cells. You can manipulated those with the `.Resize()` and `.Offset()` methods to get what you need.

Comment: How could I make MyDestRange dynamic?

Comment: Use the `.Offset()` function like `Range("FixedAddress").Offset(0,skip).Resize(N,1)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your named range has a name like "MyRange", something like this:

```
Dim srcRange as Range, destRange as Range

Set srcRange = Range("MyRange")
Set destRange = Workbooks("Data2").Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(srcRange.Rows.Count, srcRange.Columns.Count)

destRange.Value = srcRange.Value
```

Comment: Thanks! you answered my next quetion

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("Named_Range_Name_Here").copy

Range("Sheet_Name").Range("Cell Reference").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Pasting to a single cell will paste data just as you would. It will start the paste from there and pastes the names range down, unless you choose to Transpose it.